# Using Qt resources system with vs2010 add-in

Tags: qt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Embedded JPG resources not loading in Qt application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241141/embedded-jpg-resources-not-loading-in-qt-application)

This is the first time I manage app's resources by Qt built-in tool.

I have set up a Qt4 Application project in vc++2010. Then I created new .qrc file using Qt Resource Editor and used attached files. While I'm running app on my (the same) machine everything works fine, but when I'm executing it on other PCs (with clean installed XP / 7 / vista) the attached images aren't displayed.

May I should install Qt libraries on the target machines to make it work properly?
Or maybe I've forgotten about some important Qt Resources System functionality?

Comment: Are you sure that you builded release version?

Comment: Yes, I tried only release on other PCs.

Comment: Show me your code, how you insert your resources into widgets.

Comment: Are you really sure that you are using the images from resources? And what is the image format?

Comment: <code>label->setPixmap(QPixmap(QString::fromUtf8(":/Resources/jesien.jpg")));</code> The app crashes even if the code is generated automatically (as presented).

Comment: ANd u are sure that you have jesien.jpg in resources folder?

Comment: Yes. Furthermore, there is generated qrc_myproject.cpp file which contains huge byte array with my image.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241141/embedded-jpg-resources-not-loading-in-qt-application

Comment: Few words about environment on target (diffrent) computers: I tested it on: { clean installed xp, common xp, win7, win vista }. On every isn't installed Qt or VS, so I put some dlls in folder with my program: { msvcp100.dll, msvcr100.dll, QtCore4.dll, QtGui4.dll }.

Comment: Hey! It worked. How to sign your reply Roku as the answer?

Comment: Well, I rather mark this question as a duplicate.