# Jpeg read errors using QImage in release builds

Tags: c++, qt, load, jpeg, qimage

Has anyone experienced problems using Qt and the QImage's class load method when attempting to load jpeg images.  The loading works perfectly in debug mode using QtCreator but fails completely when attempting to load the same jpeg images when the application is built and thereafter run in release mode.

```
QImage myImage;
QString s = QDir().toNativeSeparators(QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, QString("Import Image...")));
if ( !myImage.load(s) ) {
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setWindowTitle(this->windowTitle());
    msgBox.setWindowIcon(this->windowIcon());
    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Information);
    msgBox.setText("Image could not be loaded.");
    msgBox.exec();
    return;
}
```

I've concluded I may be missing a specific dynamic link library but cannot foresee which one it would be.  Please note that in release mode, I am still able to process PNG images.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux? If you run your release build with QtCreator it works?

Comment: jpg plugin maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241141/embedded-jpg-resources-not-loading-in-qt-application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800346/showing-jpg-image-with-qt-does-not-work-with-release-executable

Comment: Yes jpeg's work when I run the application from release build within QtCreator but not when I deploy it onto standalone windows.  Yes using Windows.  Everything works excluding jpeg loading.

Comment: So the jpg plugin is missing. There are about a dozen questions (and answers too) concerning the same problem in the Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Add the imageplugins(or imageformats) folder to your build. Using jpg requires libjpeg.dll to be available for the executable. Look under your Qt installation dir for the required files.

Comment: I've done this but with no success, my imageformats folder contains qgif2.dll, qico4.dll, qjpeg4.dll, qmng4.dll, qsvg4.dll, qtiff4.dll.

Comment: my folder contains: qgif4.dll, qgifd4.dll, qico4.dll, qicod4.dll, qjpeg.dll, qjpeg4.dll, qjpegd4.dll, qmng4.dll, qmngd4.dll, qsvg4.dll, qsvgd4.dll, qtga4.dll, qtgad4.dll, qtiff4.dll, qtiffd4.dll

Comment: still cannot load jpeg images

Comment: try putting the imageformats folder with your executable where it can find the dlls.

Comment: the only images I am able to open in release is png files.  I can access all types of images within Qt but only png when it is distributed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of the dll's needed by your applications is not being found in yout PATH environment variable. You can use [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) to discover which dll's are missing.

Comment: I've attempted to include the plugins/imageformats folder with my release exe.  I've concluded it is impossible to ship a qt exe with jpeg support.

Comment: Even attempted 
    QString sDir = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();
    a.addLibraryPath(sDir+"/plugins");

Comment: Impossible it is not, since I've done. Have you checked Dependency Walker output?