# Qt grab widget and save image

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following problem. I want to grab a widget and save it as an image. I want to save it as png, jpeg, and tiff. I have written the following code:

```
QString s =  QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Save as", "Choose a filename", "PNG(*.png);; TIFF(*.tiff *.tif);; JPEG(*.jpg *.jpeg)");

std::string current_string = s.toLocal8Bit().constData();
//current_string = current_string + ".png";

char * buffer = new char[current_string.length()];
std::string temp = buffer;
char* temp2 = &temp[0];
strcpy(buffer, current_string.c_str());

char* pch = strtok (temp2,".");
pch = strtok (NULL, ".");


if(!QPixmap::grabWindow(m_widget->winId()).save(buffer,pch))
{
    QMessageBox::warning(this, "File could not be saved", "ok", QMessageBox::Ok);
}
```

This works fine on my laptop. When I make a Visual Studio Setup it also works fine on my laptop, but when I install it on another pc, then the png format works fine (saves the right image), but jpeg and tif can't be saved. Then I tried it on a further pc, but there I tried it directly in Visual Studio with the project file. There I have all project settings like on my pc etc. and there jpeg and tif don't work. PNG works but it only saves a white image on that pc. Further I also tried there the installation file and its the same PNG = white image.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need image plugins, see for example this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241141/embedded-jpg-resources-not-loading-in-qt-application

Comment: I have already tried to copy the 4 dlls in the exe folder. But it doesn't work either. And it would also not explain why on one pc the png image is white and why it doesn't work to save jpeg and png files, when I tried it there in Visual Studio debug mode. ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the simplest way to save a widget as an image. This approach works on Qt 5:

```
ui->myWidget->grab().save("image.png");
```

Qt doc.:

- [QPixmap **QWidget::grab**(const QRect &rectangle = QRect(QPoint(0, 0), QSize(-1, -1)))](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grab)
- [bool **QPixmap::save**(const QString &fileName, const char *format = nullptr, int quality = -1) const](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#save).

Comment: Nice short answer - it could be  improved by adding a link to the documentation and some summary/description of its contents (since links disappear or move) - such as the section or version of the docs where you found the reference.  Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1):

The plugins don't go in the application EXE folder directly, but a "plugins" folder under the application folder. I've also had to place it in an "imageformats" folder instead of "plugins" at least once, I believe. That might have been a different platform/special build.

See this [Qt deployment guide](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html) for windows.

Also, your "new char[]" call is probably going to eventually crash. You need to reserve space for the null character:

```
char * buffer = new char[current_string.length() + 1];
```

Also also, you don't need all the std::string stuff just to get an extension. That's likely to just be frustrating over time.

```
QString saveFilename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Save as", "Choose a filename", "PNG(*.png);; TIFF(*.tiff *.tif);; JPEG(*.jpg *.jpeg)");

QString saveExtension = "PNG";
int pos = saveFilename.lastIndexOf('.');
if (pos >= 0)
    saveExtension = saveFilename.mid(pos + 1);

if(!QPixmap::grabWidget(m_widget).save(saveFilename, qPrintable(saveExtension)))
{
    // since you have a widget, just use grabWidget() here. winId() would possibly have
    // portability issues on other platforms.  qPrintable(saveExtension) is effectively
    // the same as saveExtension.toLocal8Bit().constData()

    QMessageBox::warning(this, "File could not be saved", "ok", QMessageBox::Ok);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. This works. But I still have the problem that on 5 pcs the grab window works, and on one pc it saves a white image.

Comment: Hmm.. strange. Is there anything different about that PC?  (Different video card, video driver version, OS... ?)

Comment: It is a  Nvidia GTX470. The other PCs are also Nvidia and one of them has a AMD card.